# Why is ol-mapbox-style applyStyle strip part of the url in the json style file

Tags: openlayers, arcgis

using the latest Open Layers (ol) and ol-mapbox-style packages.  have a json style file created with esri's editor.  trying to display a basemap vector layer.  but when I call applyStyle from ol-mapbox-style, it strips the VectorTyleServer string from the source url and throws a 400 invalid url.  The applyStyle can also form the VectorTileSource from the waterJson file and also strips the VectorTileServer string from the url.  so that is why the source property in the layer is commented out but I left it there for visibility into what the url is supposed to be.  this url is in the waterJson style file along with others.  what am I doing wrong?

The url's in our waterJson style file:

```
{
  "version": 8,
  "sprite": "https://cdn.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/items/de26a3cf4cc9451298ea173c4b324736/resources/styles/../sprites/sprite",
  "glyphs": "https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/resources/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
  "sources": {
    "esri": {
      "type": "vector",
      "url": "https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer"
    }
  }
```

The Javascript:

```
import VectorTileLayer from 'ol/layer/VectorTile';
import VectorTileSource from 'ol/source/VectorTile';
import MVT from 'ol/format/MVT';
import { applyStyle } from 'ol-mapbox-style';
import waterJson from './styles/water.json'

    this._waterLayer = new VectorTileLayer({
      className: 'waterLayer',
      visible: true,
      declutter: true,
      // source: new VectorTileSource({
      //   url: 'https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}.pbf',
      //   format: new MVT(),
      // }),
    });
    applyStyle(this._waterLayer, waterJson, 'esri')
      .then((r) => console.log('waterJson style applied to waterlayer'))
      .catch((e) => console.log('error applying waterJson style to waterlayer', e));
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this https://github.com/openlayers/ol-mapbox-style/issues/858#issuecomment-1477544477 help?

Comment: I don't think we have any relative url's in our style file.  I've updated the question with the top of the file that contains the url's.  Also, we use applyStyle, and not apply, which I've read are a little different from each other.  I've looked through these issues before and didn't see anything that seem to apply, unless I am dismissing stuff I shouldn't.

Comment: if you take the url from the error message, and paste TileMapSever back into it and paste into a browser, you will see data come back in the browser.

Comment: The `tiles` url inside `https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer` is relative.  You might be able to fix that simply by changing the `sources` url in your json to `https://basemaps.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Basemap_v2/VectorTileServer/` otherwise you could use a `transformRequest`

Comment: That’s what the sources url already is i the waterJson file, see the addition I added to the question that shows the beginning of the jaon file.

Comment: I’ve tried the longer sources url that is in the commented out code, and tried just letting it get from the style file. In both cases TileMapServer gets dropped from the url

Comment: The sources url in your json does not have the final `/`

Comment: I made it work by downgrading ol from 7.4 to 6.14.1 which downgraded ol-mapbox-style from 10.4.0 to 7.1.1. It didn’t work on every release in between. Our style files were generated a while ago with the arcgis online tool. Does the current tool generate different files now that are only compatible with mapbox 8, 9, and 10?

Comment: I’d like to make it work with the latest versions. Is there a tool to update style files?

Comment: Either add a final `/` after `/VectorTileServer` to the source url in your jsons or add a transform request to do that as in https://codesandbox.io/s/mapbox-style-forked-dqds2v?file=/main.js  It will work with any version.